# Adding row of data to an array via iterator

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am iterating through a directory full of sub directories, looking for the newest file at each level.

The code below does this, but I need to be able to add each line/loop of the iterator to an array so that at the end I can output all the data in tabular format for use in Excel.

Any advice on how I can do this?

```
    $arr = get-childItem -Path "\\network location\directory" | select FullName
    $res = @()

    foreach($fp  in $arr)
    {

    get-childItem -Path $fp.FullName | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 Directory, FullName, Name, LastWriteTime

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner for you, split onto multiple lines for readability with the backtick escape character. You can copy paste this and it will run as is. The csv file will be created in the folder where you run this from.

```
dir -rec -directory | `
    foreach {
        dir $_.fullname -file | `
        sort -Descending lastwritetime | `
        select -first 1
    } | `
    export-csv newestfiles.csv
```

`dir` is an alias for `get-childitem`. `foreach` is an alias for `foreach-object`. `%`, `gci` and `ls` are even shorter aliases for `get-childitem`. Note that I am avoiding storing things in arrays, as this is doubling the work required. There is no need to enumerate the folders, and then enumerate the array afterwards as two separate operations.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to pipe the results into $res. So adding `| %{$res += $_}` should do the trick

```
  $arr = get-childItem -Path "\\network location\directory" | select FullName
  $res = @()


    foreach($fp  in $arr)
    {

     get-childItem -Path $fp.FullName | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 Directory, FullName, Name, LastWriteTime | % {$res += $_}

    }

    $res | % {write-host $_}
```